# Users by reputation - month view broken again

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, users

The [user listings](https://stackoverflow.com/users) defaults to showing users by reputation for the past 'period', where 'period' can be set to the current week, month, quarter or year.

Since August 1st, however, the view for [this month](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) is broken, in that reputation for most users has not been set back to 0 after July.

This is what the first page looks like right now:

[image: month ranking]

Note that close to 7k in 10 days is not something even I can manage unless I can get a 500 point bonus most of those days :-)

For other the month-to-date total is correct, so they are ranked somewhere on later pages. Try to find Gordon Linoff or Jon Skeet or T.J. Crowder, for example.

The [stackexchange.com top user rankings for the month](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2016-08-01) (updated once a day) are correct still.

Can a dev please pull loose whatever got stuck here?

Comment: It's also been reported on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281997/something-wrong-with-month-user-rep-some-users-show-quarterly-figures).  The devs are aware but have yet to kick the monthly rep job.

Comment: Ah, I assumed it was SO only, so reported it here. Should have checked!

Comment: I've poked a dev about it.

Comment: @bluefeet was it with a pointy stick?

Comment: Looks like it's caching.

Comment: @bluefeet "I've poked a dev about it." TMI

Comment: @TravisJ Obligatory link: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/.

Comment: This was resolved eventually.

Comment: @Taryn now you're the dev and it's [happening again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403382/7296893), will you poke yourself? ;-)