# How can I find out the reason for losing near 300 points of reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation

Today, I have noticed that my reputation fell below 5K. It was above 5K like I don't know 5-10 days ago. However I couldn't find the reason of this change in reputation. Probably it is related to Documentation. I don't know maybe an example is deleted. How can I learn the reason?

By the way I did inspect the [mentioned question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/1519458) before asking this question. However it seems to me that it is not covering my case. If the reputation loss is due to the documentation as I guess (which is not covered in that question), it would be better to see actually what happened. Which document is deleted? How much I lost?

I even checked the "show removed posts" checkbox as mentioned in the allegedly duplicate question's answer. And yet I can not find the reason for reputation lost in my case. How is that an answer to my question? If I am missing something I will be more than happy to learn.

Comment: Never visited the reputation history in your profile? Link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1519458/nuri-tasdemir?tab=reputation

Comment: Of course I do. However according to my reputation history, I never got above 5K. But I know I did

Comment: I even checked http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: Then you have to wait until a mod can look into this matter. Might not take that long.

Comment: All I see in your history is that the system recalculated your reputation today, resulting in a change from 5171 to 4724. No vote invalidation was involved, near as I can tell. Don't see any other obvious events, so my guess would be something having to do with Documentation. Perhaps an entry of yours was removed?

Comment: @CodyGray that post needs an update to cater for the insane reputation rules around Documentation ... not hammering for that dupe yet.

Comment: Oh, "Documentation". Yes, clearly what that post needs is an update to make it twice as long. :-(

Comment: You could add another answer?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I left a link to this question in the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5722691#5722691) in the hope this gets picked up by an CM/Developer.

Comment: I still wonder how people with more than a hundred or so points even *notice* that they've lost reputation. I could lose 480 points from one day to the next and I would literally never know it. Do you actually memorize your reputation count and compare it from one day to the next? Otherwise, the site would have to be *notifying* you that you lost reputation, in which case, that notification would have a reason accompanying it.

Comment: @CodyGray - Likely the OP noticed they were > halfway to the 10K mark one day and not the next.

Comment: I'd say that the reputation history not giving details about rep lost from documentation is a bug.

Comment: @CodyGray Easy. When you have 150k like yourself, it's easy to forget. When you have 5k like OP or me, every point is relevant. Whether you have 150k or 1500k is functionally identical, if I had an extra 5k points I'd have 10k tools.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill: I looked at your history and was able to see a -85 recalc event (6485 => 6400). It occurred around the time Nick Craver did a [global recalc](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340787/1438). Not sure what _exactly_ caused the change in reputation, but it's likely the result of user merges that didn't get accounted for when they occurred. I'm still investigating the change the question is asking about. I'm not certain it is Docs related.

Comment: @JonEricson I appreciate you looking into my reputation issues.  The revised rep still seemed to have a math issue: 6400 on Jan 3, plus +-73 rep earned since didn't match my rep as of this morning of 6451.  Unfortunately, my rep changed again, and is now -520 from what it was this morning, and still no indication of why.  I can clearly see that multiple documentation scores are now missing, however still no tracking of the changes.  There seems to be quite a lot of inconsistent record keeping and calculation going on with my reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details on the bug are in [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343581/documentation-example-contributor-corruption-results-in-reputation-drop/345211#345211).