# Is there a bug with searching users by reputation for the month?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Right now when I search for users and sort by reputation I'm getting this screenshot for the month.

[image: Month tab: 2020-12-01 to today]

However, the week gives a different ranking, and less rep gained even though it's a longer time period because as the tooltips show, in the month tab, it's from 2020-12-01 to today while in the week tab, it's from 2020-11-29 to today.

[image: Week tab: 2020-11-29 to today]

I would assume this is a bug and just wanted to see what others thought?

Comment: Hmmm The tooltip suggests that month should be from the start of the current month, but this makes me wonder if it's possibly doing "Last 4 weeks" or maybe even "Previous month" on the back end. Good catch.

Comment: @ErikA In that case, the tooltip is wrong. So, still a bug, I think.

Comment: @ErikA That would make it inconsistent with the "Voters" tab, that resets on the beginning of a month or week respectively.

Comment: Yeah, this happens from time to time. The start-of-the-month update broke half-way through the reset somewhere.

Comment: See previous reports: [Users by reputation - month view broken again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332118) and [Users by reputation - Year view broken again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340780) (it is not limited to months).

Answer (score 5):

The scheduled job that resets the reputation for the month failed on December 1, 2020, so data being displayed also included November 2020.

We kicked off a rep recalc which has completed. The data should be displaying correctly now. We're also going to change the process to batch the update to prevent future time-outs on the query.

Comment: The problem appears to have been fixed on [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Thank you.